# Error running clang while installing amazonka

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm trying to use amazonka-cost-explorer in my Haskell stack project. The latest supported ghc version by amazonka is 8.10.7 ([here](https://github.com/brendanhay/amazonka#supported-platforms-and-ghc-versions)).

I added `amazonka-cost-explorer` to my package.yaml file. Added

```
- amazonka-cost-explorer-1.6.1@sha256:e81d42dbdef267dc6d2cce70548f0c5170c875f235ca26cba5c00fcf88ebcc43,3331
```

to my extra-deps in stack.yaml. Used `stack --resolver lts-18.28` build to build the project. I'm getting the following error with clang.

```
z80000gn/T/ghc29668_0/ghc_1.s:3394:2: error:
cryptonite            >      error: instruction requires: sha3
cryptonite            >             eor3.16b        v0, v1, v0, v2
cryptonite            >             ^
cryptonite            >      |
cryptonite            > 3394 |         eor3.16b        v0, v1, v0, v2
cryptonite            >      |  ^
cryptonite            > 
cryptonite            > <no location info>: error:
cryptonite            >     Error running clang! you need clang installed to use the LLVM backend
cryptonite            >     (or GHC tried to execute clang incorrectly)
cryptonite            > `clang' failed in phase `Clang (Assembler)'. (Exit code: 1)
Progress 1/12

--  While building package cryptonite-0.29
```

So far I have used the lts-20 as resolver for my project and it worked fine. Since amaonka supports only ghc 8.10.7 I used lts-18.28 as resolver.
I'm using Mac m1 Monterey (12.6.2). I installed stack via ghcup. I installed llvm@12 via brew and when I type `clang --version` I get the following output.

```
Homebrew clang version 12.0.1
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm@12/bin
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

EDIT: As @Ismor pointed out in comments, I tried building directly from the latest commit from the main branch of amazonka repo. Stack build succeeds with lts-20 resolver itself.

Comment: I think `ghc-8.10.7` is not well supported in the new mac architecture. You have to use `ghc-9.2` or newer (to my best knowledge). Noticem that I don't know If that's the problem, but is only a piece of advice.

Comment: Apparently amazonka is stuck in a pre-release version. Some [people](https://github.com/brendanhay/amazonka/discussions/716#discussioncomment-4669849) are using the git source directly

Comment: Thanks @Ismor. I tried building directly from the latest commit in main branch. Stack build succeeds with lts-20 resolver itself.